# remove left characters in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a varchar column with some data like: 0000000000,0000000123,0000000010,...
I want to cast this column into an integer, but I get the error it is not a number. So I thought I have to remove the left 0 of the varchar, but how do I do that?

Comment: Is the data in that column actually a comma delimited list of numbers like this, or is one field just `0000000123` and the next record contains `000000010`, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `to_number` function

```
select to_number('000001') from dual it will return 1
```

so your case

`select to_number(column) from your_table`

Comment: @Bigjo I'm curious how were casting this before that you were erroring?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your problem is.  Both these work when I try them:

```
select cast('0000000123' as int), to_number('0000000123')
from dual;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/XIKLB34321) is a rextester illustrating that this works in Oracle.

Comment: @Bigjo . . . I added a Rextester.  Either version works in Oracle.